# jQuery selector that doesn't include children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I haven't seen a question that is exactly this, so here goes:

Imagine I have this html structure:

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="text">
        Button
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the ".button" element, but not the ".btext" element. Meaning, I want to do something like

`$(".button")` that doesn't include the ".btext". I want to use this for a .hover() match, but I don't want hovering on the text to trigger the event.

Is there a way to do this, or is it just not possible with html?

Comment: Are you looking for the `mouseenter` event? Seems that would be the correct way to do it rather than `hover()`.

Comment: @zhiayang: ".btext" this class is not exist in your sample HTML structure.

Comment: IMHO, if you want the two elements to behave differently, they should be siblings, not parent and child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check event target element. Just execute necessary action after you check `e.target`. For example  it can look like this:

```
$('.button').mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover', !$(e.target).hasClass('text'));
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/8LKZV/

Answer (score 1):

when the hover event triggers it will return the element, so you can find it in the call back

```
$('button').hover(function(e){
  if (e.target == $('.text')){
         return false;
     }
});
```

**Edit:**

@Alnitak is correct, that should have been.

```
   if ($(e.target).hasClass('text'))
```

Comment: it _shouldn't_ work - you can't compare an element to a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an event to bubble from child to parent and you are using jQuery, you can use `event.stopPropagation` on the child like so:

```
$(".text").hover(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[link to docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NtbH/)